# Error in executing powershell script SQL Server

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that am running but it keeps getting errors. Please see below:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll' or one of its dependencies
```

How can I fix this problem?
I have checked online for solution but could not get any help

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far that led to this error? Post code! Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It sounds like you need to install more sql components, or the required components aren't in the version you're using. Or potentially a 32/64bit issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution from this page:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35832.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser.aspx